# javascript mind blowing behavior

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have this set of functions and it refuses to run

```
alert('Ok I reach in if 1')
```

or

```
alert('Ok I reach in if 2')
```

despite that I have no html or javascript errors.

alert(res[3]) before if output 'baza'

alert(typeof res[3]) before if output 'string'

```
function ataseazaPoza(id, poza) {
  tip = '';
  if (id.search("dragzonesortpic") == 0) {
    tip = 'sort';
  } else {
    tip = 'baza';
  }
  http.open('get', 'produse_ataseazaPoza.php?id=' + id + '&image=' + poza + '&tip=' + tip + '&nocache=' + Math.random());
  http.onreadystatechange = ataseazaPozaReply;
  http.send(null);
}

function ataseazaPozaReply() {
  if (http.readyState == 4) {
    var response = http.responseText;
    res = response.split(";");
    if (res[0] == 'er') {
      alert('Eroare: ' + res[1] + ' ' + res[2]);
    } else {
      keys = res[2].split("-");
      alert(res[3]);
      if (res[3] == 'baza') {
        alert('Ok I reach in if 1');
        elemRo = document.getElementById('rowuv' + res[1]).style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
        elemOv = document.getElementById('dragzoneuv' + res[1]);
        imgurl = "url('../prod_imagini/" + keys[0] + "/" + keys[0] + "/" + res[2] + "')";
        elemOv.style.backgroundImage = imgurl;
      }
      if (res[3] == 'sort') {
        alert('Ok I reach in if 2');
        randPlus = parseInt(res[1]) + 1;
        elemRo = document.getElementById('sortHoverDrop' + res[1]).style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
        elemOv = document.getElementById('dragzonesortpic' + res[1]);
        imgurl = "url('../prod_imagini/" + keys[0] + "/" + keys[0] + "/" + res[2] + "')";
        document.getElementById('pozaHiddenSort' + res[1]).value = imgurl;
        elemOv.style.backgroundImage = imgurl;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why it not enter if?[real code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmYuG.jpg)

Comment: sometimes for whatever reason teh errors dont show in the console and you have to put the in a try..catch and alert the message.

Comment: Use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`, so you can see all the characters in the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have some whitespace on the end of your string. You can use [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove extra whitespace.

```js
var withWhitespace = 'baza ';
console.log(withWhitespace + ' == "baza"', withWhitespace == 'baza');
var withoutWhitespace = withWhitespace.trim();
console.log(withoutWhitespace + ' == "baza"', withoutWhitespace == 'baza');
```

Comment: You are a genious! That was the problem I have like 5 empty rows... don't now from where (php outputs ok). I remove them with .substring(0,4) while string will always have 4 characters.